# Print specific number line of files list

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Good day to all,

Today, I was wondering how to print the same number line of different files.

The traditional way to print **a** specific line of **a** file is:

```
# Print line number 52
sed -n '52p' # method 1
sed '52!d' # method 2
sed '52q;d' # method 3
```

But, when I want to use it like:

```
sed '52q;d' Files*
```

It only prints the line number 52 of the first file beginning with: *Files*.

Thanks so much in advance for any clue.

Comment: See my updated answer to address the issue with `xargs` passing all arguments at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk to print line 52 of a list of files like this:

```
awk 'FNR==52' Files*
```

The built-in variable `FNR` is the current record number of the current file. Using the default record separator, this corresponds to the line number. When FNR is equal to 52, the expression evaluates to true so awk prints the line.

It's potentially a premature optimisation but you might also want to skip to the next file rather than processing all lines after the 52nd. In GNU awk, this can be done using the `nextfile` statement:

```
awk 'FNR==52 {print; nextfile}' Files*
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe it through `xargs` to run each file through `sed`. Note the argument `-n 1` to make `xargs` only pass one argument at a time to `sed`.

```
ls Files* | xargs -n 1 sed -n '52p'
```

Comment: I was wondering how xargs works. Am I able to ask you for a short explanation? xargs is so useful, but I don't know how to use it and what was created it for. Thanks

Comment: @Ajejandro, `xargs` takes its own standard input, and transforms it into command line arguments for the program which is given to it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head) command to easily see the first n lines of a file:

```
ls Files* | xargs head -n 52
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope. It prints all lines from the first until the 52th of all files. I only want the 52th of all files

Answer (score 0):

`q` in `sed '52q;d' Files*` makes `sed` ***quit*** on the 52th line of the first file so naturally it would only print the first 52 lines.

Comment: Oh so that wasn't the question my bad.

Comment: @merlin2011 I don't find that not necessary.

Comment: Obviously it's your call, but this answer, while conveying useful information, does not address the OP's actual question.