# How to print specific line of a group of files in defferent directories

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, glob

I'm going to print specific line of a list of files which are in different sub directories. Say we have a main folder and t001 to t010 sub folders. I have a data.text in each one.
If all files were in a single directory we could simply have from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984933/print-specific-number-line-of-files-list):

```
awk 'FNR==3' Files*
```

but here files are in sub directories. Do you have any idea?

**Edit**: 
I think we can type:

```
awk 'FNR==3' ./t*/data.txt
```

Here I can't locate the file that has the data I was looking for. When I use :

```
grep -r -A 1 "string" *
```

I can see what I'm looking for in line after the `string` and also find the directory, but here I just need the line below the string.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts !!

Comment: It wasn't an applause yeah?! :-)

Comment: What's the relation between `string` and `FNR == 3`?

Comment: `string` is at 2nd line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -name "data.txt" -exec awk 'FNR==3' '{}' \;
```

See [how to run find -exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec)

#### Edit

If you also need to print the filename as in the grep output then you can do it with `FILENAME` like so

```
find . -name "data.txt" -exec awk 'FNR==3 {print FILENAME ": " $0}' '{}' \;
```

or

```
awk 'FNR==3 {print FILENAME ": " $0}' ./t*/data.txt
```

Look for `FILENAME` in `man awk` for more information.

Comment: Thank you. but there is a problem here and also in my way. When we print the first line to see the data, it's unknown the directory of file. I want to see the first line and then go to that file that has what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Abolfazl updated my answer with what I think you are looking for

Comment: amazing! yep that what I was looking around.